# Determine whether instance of arbitrary type can be set to arbitrarily typed value

Tags: go, reflection

Is it possible to determine (using `reflect`) whether an instance of an arbitrary type can be set to an arbitrary value, i.e. to determine whether `Value.Set()` would panic due to type incompatibility?

An MCVE is set out below. What I want to know is effectively 'can I write `set()` without using the defer/recover construct?'

I'd like to avoid `defer` not only because it seems ugly, but because `Value.Set()` may panic for other reasons.

Note this is *not* merely a question of comparing the types for equality, as the `o2` example below shows.

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

// set a value V to interface i, returning true if this can be done, else false
//
// CAN WE WRITE THIS WITHOUT HAVING TO USE DEFER / RECOVER?
//
func set(v reflect.Value, i interface{}) bool {
    success := true
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            success = false
        }
    }()
    v.Set(reflect.ValueOf(i))
    return success
}

// get the type of a typed nil
func getType(typedNil interface{}) reflect.Type {
    return reflect.TypeOf(typedNil).Elem()
}

func main() {
    t1 := getType((*int)(nil))
    o1 := reflect.New(t1)

    t2 := getType((*interface{})(nil))
    o2 := reflect.New(t2)

    var ok bool
    var aInt = 456
    var aString string = "hello"
    var aUint uint = 123

    // Set o1 to various types
    
    ok = set(o1.Elem(), aInt) // Should return true
    fmt.Printf("After o1 set to aInt returned %v: obj is type %T content '%v'\n", ok, o1.Elem().Interface(), o1.Elem().Interface())

    ok = set(o1.Elem(), aString) // Should return false
    fmt.Printf("After o1 set to aString returned %v: obj is type %T content '%v'\n", ok, o1.Elem().Interface(), o1.Elem().Interface())

    ok = set(o1.Elem(), aUint) // Should return false
    fmt.Printf("After o1 set to aUint returned %v: obj is type %T content '%v'\n", ok, o1.Elem().Interface(), o1.Elem().Interface())

    fmt.Println("")

    // Set o2 to various types
    ok = set(o2.Elem(), aInt)  // Should return true
    fmt.Printf("After o2 set to aInt returned %v: obj is type %T content '%v'\n", ok, o2.Elem().Interface(), o2.Elem().Interface())

    ok = set(o2.Elem(), aString) // Should return true
    fmt.Printf("After o2 set to aString returned %v: obj is type %T content '%v'\n", ok, o2.Elem().Interface(), o2.Elem().Interface())
    
    ok = set(o2.Elem(), aUint) // Should return true
    fmt.Printf("After o2 set to aUint returned %v: obj is type %T content '%v'\n", ok, o2.Elem().Interface(), o2.Elem().Interface())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) has a `Type.AssignableTo()` method:

```
// AssignableTo reports whether a value of the type is assignable to type u.
AssignableTo(u Type) bool
```

So you may use this to simplify your `set()` function:

```
func set(v reflect.Value, i interface{}) bool {
    if !reflect.TypeOf(i).AssignableTo(v.Type()) {
        return false
    }
    v.Set(reflect.ValueOf(i))
    return true
}
```

Output will be the same (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fGP5QNQkz4t)):

```
After o1 set to aInt returned true: obj is type int content '456'
After o1 set to aString returned false: obj is type int content '456'
After o1 set to aUint returned false: obj is type int content '456'

After o2 set to aInt returned true: obj is type int content '456'
After o2 set to aString returned true: obj is type string content 'hello'
After o2 set to aUint returned true: obj is type uint content '123'
```

You may also (additionally) call [`Value.CanSet()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.CanSet) to detect certain "unsettable" scenarios:

> CanSet reports whether the value of v can be changed. A Value can be changed only if it is addressable and was not obtained by the use of unexported struct fields. If CanSet returns false, calling Set or any type-specific setter (e.g., SetBool, SetInt) will panic.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I was sure this should exist but it's mysteriously missing from the index at https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/ - though it's there lower down.

Comment: @abligh It's missing in the index because `reflect.Type` is an interface, not a concrete implementation, and methods of interfaces are not listed in the index, only methods of concrete types.